# Find the angles of the trapezoid if $AD:BC=5:1$

Tags: geometry

In an isosceles trapezoid $ABCD$, $AD$ is parallel to $BC$, the distance from the vertex $A$ to the straight line $CD$ is equal to the length of a leg. Find the angles of the trapezoid if $AD:BC=5:1$.

---

Let $AD=5x,BC=x,AB=CD=y$. Let $AE$ be the perpendicular to $CD$ and $AE=y$. I cannot solve further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Figure]

In $\triangle CED,\displaystyle\tan\angle D=\frac{y\sin\angle D}{2x}$

In $\triangle AFD, \displaystyle\tan\angle D=\frac y{5x\cos\angle D}$

Equate the two,

$\implies\sin2\angle D=4/5\therefore\angle D=\frac12\sin^{-1}\Big(\frac45\Big)\approx26.5\deg$

Answer (score 1):

I'll sketch the start of the solution.

Let $\theta:=\angle ADE$ so repeated use of Pythagoras gives $AC^2=y^2+\left(y-\sqrt{25x^2-y^2}\right)^2$, while the cosine rule gives $AC^2=25x^2+y^2-10xy\cos\theta$. Equating these, $y=5x\sin\theta$. On the other hand, $y=2x\sec\theta$. Can you work out $\sin 2\theta$?